# Unknown Unbit S.a.s. extension

Tags: macos, big-sur, kernel-extensions

Today I got this error on my Macbook Pro (Big Sur 11.2.3 (20D91)):

> A program tried to load new system extension(s) signed by “Unbit S.a.s.” that need to be updated by the developer.

The name does not ring a bell and I did not find a reference or an option to allow it inside of the Settings under Security & Privacy.

So what piece of Software or driver is this extension referring to.

PS: I do know that the issue is known in general but I'm posting this that other people with that same extension have some reference and might find this post when googling for the message.